# How can i color points of a graph randomly with 3 different colors in R using R basic only

Tags: r, random, graph, graphics, colors

I am working with datasets `iris` in R. I need to make a graph with axis X=Petal.Length and axis Y=Petal.Width.
It was simple. But I need to colors the points of the graph in 3 different colors randomly. I found the hexadecimal value of each color:

- orange: `#ff8000`
- pink:   `#ff80c0`
- yellow: `#ffff00`

Here are the color that I need:

[image: colors needed]

I tried to use `rgb` function but it was without success.
Someone could help me to find how to color the points of the graphs with these 3 colors randomly please?

Here is my code for the the plot, it's just the graph with no specifics colors yet:

```
plot(iris$Petal.Length, iris$Petal.Width, xlab = "Petal Lenght", ylab = "Petal Width", pch=18)
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just `sample` those colours to the appropriate length and feed them to the `col` parameter:

```
my_colours <- sample(c("#ff8000", "#ff80c0", "#ffff00"), nrow(iris), replace = TRUE)

plot(iris$Petal.Length, iris$Petal.Width, 
     xlab = "Petal Length", ylab = "Petal Width", pch=18, col = my_colours)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could also try by concatenating the colours to col function

```
plot(iris$Petal.Length, iris$Petal.Width, xlab = "Petal Lenght", ylab = "Petal Width", pch=18, col = c("#ff8000","#ff80c0","#ffff00"))
```

[image]